# angular2 with visual studio 2015

Tags: angular

I am trying to set up my angular 2 application in visual studio 2015 (with update 1). But am getting and error during the typescript compile - Cannot find module '@angular/core'  at import { NgModule }    from '@angular/core';. I have also edited the project file and given the below entries but still the error is popping up. Can somebody please help me on this?

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>Node</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss your node_module. Try restoring **package.json** by right clicking on package.json file and click restore package.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But i tried restoring the package as well still its giving me the same error. I believe its an issue with Typescript Compiler. I am using Visual studio 2015 with Update1 and the typescript version which i tried is 1.7 and 2.2

Comment: You should get  `====npm command completed with exit code 0====` after restoring. Did you get 0 or did u get 1?@Subin